# Cannot execute k8s module

Tags: macos, kubernetes, ansible, minikube

My code in `tasks/main.yml`.

```
- name: Check Istio services
  k8s_info:
    api_version: v1
    kind: Service
    namespace: istio-system
```

But it returns;

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ImportError: No module named kubernetes
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "error": "No module named kubernetes",

"msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on Gihu's-MacBook-Pro.local's Python /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python.
```

Why does this issue happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Execute command;

`sudo pip install --upgrade --user openshift`

Answer (score 1):

the install of the openshift (and really a whole ansible install) is required on the target host

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error indicates that "ImportError: No module named kubernetes", so I tried with `pip install anisble kubernetes`, and it works~

Comment: You did that on the remote host right?

Comment: no, on the local host