# Ansible K8s module: Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on Python /usr/bin/python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, kubernetes, ansible, openshift

The env

> Ansible 2.9.6 (python3)

Tried to run a simple playbook

```
- hosts: master
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: create name space
      k8s:
        name: testing
        api_version: v1
        kind: Namespace
        state: present
```

Getting following error

```
The full traceback is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_u121g92v/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/common.py", line 33, in <module>
    import kubernetes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kubernetes'
fatal: [192.168.20.38]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "error": "No module named 'kubernetes'",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_key": null,
            "api_version": "v1",
            "append_hash": false,
            "apply": false,
            "ca_cert": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "context": null,
            "force": false,
            "host": null,
            "kind": "Namespace",
            "kubeconfig": null,
            "merge_type": null,
            "name": "testing",
            "namespace": null,
            "password": null,
            "proxy": null,
            "resource_definition": null,
            "src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "username": null,
            "validate": null,
            "validate_certs": null,
            "wait": false,
            "wait_condition": null,
            "wait_sleep": 5,
            "wait_timeout": 120
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on k8smasternode's Python /usr/bin/python3. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
}
```

It confuses me that,

- the root cause is **"no module named kubernetes"**?
- or **"Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on Python /usr/bin/python3"**?

And how to fix that?

Any help would be appreciated!

btw,

> **Kubernetes master node has /usr/bin/python3**

Comment: Could you try `python --version` and `ansible --version | grep "python version"` and check if the versions are the same?  There is [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304938/cannot-execute-k8s-module) on stackoverflow where community member fixed it with `sudo pip install --upgrade --user openshift`, worth to try it. Additionally maybe this could work as [workaround](https://cinhtau.net/2019/02/14/ansible-openshift-python/) for that? Let me know if that help.

Comment: You need to install the `openshift` Python module dependency for the Ansible `k8s` module.

Comment: Hi @jt97, (1) `python --version` is **Python 2.7.17** ; `ansible --version | grep "python version"` is **python version = 3.6.9**.   Because there are 2 version Pythons are installed. **is that an issue**?   (2) I've tried `sudo pip install --upgrade --user openshift` but still same error  (3) I haven't tried the workaround yet (https://cinhtau.net/2019/02/14/ansible-openshift-python/)!

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard, yes, I've tried a few ways to do that but still no luck. `pip install openshift pyyaml kubernetes` and `sudo pip install --upgrade --user openshift`

Comment: The command `python3 --version` should show you the version of python3 in use. also, on my example of this error, the error says the master node's name, `k8smasternode` in your case.

Answer (score 10):

I am a bit late to the party but since I faced this today and don't see an accepted answer, I am posting what worked for me.

Since you are running the tasks on remote servers, you must have `openshift`, `pyyaml` and `kubernetes` installed on the remote machines for this to work.

Add below tasks prior to creating namespaces:

```
- name: install pre-requisites
  pip:
    name:
      - openshift
      - pyyaml
      - kubernetes
```

Comment: Thanks ! For this i had to `sudo apt install python3-pip` first, and it worked !

Answer (score 6):

Taking a look at the documentation here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/k8s_module.html

Seems like you need to have:

- python >= 2.7
- openshift >= 0.6
- PyYAML >= 3.11

One way to do this is:

```
pip install openshift pyyaml kubernetes
```

Side note, I've added kubernetes here but I believe it's a dependency of openshift.

Also we can do like this as well:

```
pip3 install openshift pyyaml kubernetes --user
```

Comment: Thanks Bruno.  I've done that `pip3 install openshift pyyaml kubernetes` but no luck still same error. here is the output `Successfully installed cachetools-4.0.0 dictdiffer-0.8.1 google-auth-1.12.0 kubernetes-11.0.0 oauthlib-3.1.0 openshift-0.11.0 python-dateutil-2.8.1 python-string-utils-1.0.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.0 ruamel.yaml-0.16.10 ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.0 urllib3-1.25.8 websocket-client-0.57.0`

Comment: I am wondering if these libs should be installed on your ansible executor or your "master", as described in your hosts field. Could you do a ```kubectl use-context <your context>```, add a "delegate_to: localhost" at the end of k8s module and try it? This is assuming your executor can connect to kube using kubectl. k8s also accepts a field called "context" which allows you to specify on what context you want to install.

Answer (score 3):

Define this variable in inventory -
`ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3`,
it must help ansible to choose right interpreter during local connection.

Answer (score 1):

You're running the playbook with `become: yes` so the extension needs to be installed for the root user as well. Just had the same problem but `sudo pip install openshift pyyaml` fixed it for me.