# Ansible K8s Install Fails - No module named Kubernetes, Failed to import the required Python Library

Tags: python-3.x, kubernetes, installation, ansible

I am running my playbook with the following command:

```
ansible-playbook kubernetes_cluster.yml -b --ask-pass -vvv
```

My error message is:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ansible_k8s_payload_2BRCdT/ansible_k8s_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/k8s/common.py", line 33, in <module>
    import kubernetes
ImportError: No module named kubernetes
fatal: [kube1.idm.nac-issa.org]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "error": "No module named kubernetes",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "api_key": null,
            "api_version": "v1",
            "append_hash": false,
            "apply": false,
            "ca_cert": null,
            "client_cert": null,
            "client_key": null,
            "context": null,
            "force": false,
            "host": null,
            "kind": "Namespace",
            "kubeconfig": "/root/.kube/config",
            "merge_type": null,
            "name": "",
            "namespace": null,
            "password": null,
            "proxy": null,
            "resource_definition": null,
            "src": null,
            "state": "present",
            "username": null,
            "validate": null,
            "validate_certs": null,
            "wait": false,
            "wait_condition": null,
            "wait_sleep": 5,
            "wait_timeout": 120
        }
    },
    "msg": "Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on kube1.idm.nac-issa.org's Python /usr/bin/python. Please read module documentation and install in the appropriate location. If the required library is installed, but Ansible is using the wrong Python interpreter, please consult the documentation on ansible_python_interpreter"
```

My environment:

```
ansible 2.9.16
  config file = /home/ansuser/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/ansuser/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Apr 16 2020, 01:36:27) [GCC 8.3.1 20191121 (Red Hat 8.3.1-5)]
```

I followed the directions from a similar question and performed the pip installs on the target host (not the management host)-
[Ansible K8s module: Failed to import the required Python library (openshift) on Python /usr/bin/python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60866755/ansible-k8s-module-failed-to-import-the-required-python-library-openshift-on)
and [Cannot execute k8s module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59304938/cannot-execute-k8s-module)
but that hasn't made any difference

```
pip3 install openshift pyyaml kubernetes and also `sudo pip3 install --upgrade --user openshift`
```

I'm stuck figuring out what to try next.  Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: did you install it on the Ansible node only? You should also install Python packages on the target nodes.

Comment: @mdaniel, thanks for the comment  when you say which  python it used I think you mean /usr/bin/python, correct?  Are you suggesting to use the -e option with my ansible command to control which python version is being used? So, if I understand correctly, I need to be sure the kubernetes module is installed in the ansible python module location but the playbook is using /usr/bin/python.  The location mismatch is causing issues?